# Alembic fails to create compound unique index

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have the following model:

```
class Table(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table'
    __table_args__ = (
        Index('bar_baz_idx', 'bar', 'baz', unique=True,
              postgresql_where='foo IS NULL AND bar IS NOT NULL '
                               'AND baz IS NOT NULL'),
        {'schema': 'custom_schema'},
    )

    foo = Column(String(80), nullable=True)
    bar = Column(String(80), nullable=True)
    baz = Column(String(80), nullable=True)
```

Which produces the following upgrade function, when I autogenerate an Alembic migration:

```
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.create_table('table',
    sa.Column('foo', sa.String(length=80), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('bar', sa.String(length=80), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('baz', sa.String(length=80), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('fxt', sa.String(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id'),
    schema='custom_schema'
    )
    op.create_index('bar_baz_idx', 'table', ['bar', 'baz'], unique=True, schema='custom_schema', postgresql_where='foo IS NULL AND bar IS NOT NULL AND baz IS NOT NULL')
```

However, this fails (on Alembic 0.9.6) with the following traceback:

```
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.4/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-1.1.15-py3.4-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/base.py", line 1727, in visit_create_index
    literal_binds=True)
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.4/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-1.1.15-py3.4-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 242, in process
    return obj._compiler_dispatch(self, **kwargs)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_compiler_dispatch'
```

Is there something obvious that I'm doing wrong here? It seems to work fine without the `postgresql_where` argument.

Comment: wrap your `postgresql_where` argument in `sqlalchemy.text()`?

Comment: yup, that was it. Thanks!